# How to open port in Ubuntu 14.04 for Sendgrid

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, sendgrid

I have problem to send email through sendgrid from my host. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html

How could I open port 25, 2525, 465 and 587 respectfully so I could send mail from sendgrid?

Thanks

Comment: That really depends what firewall you are using, but this doesn't really have anything to do with php? - Also, I know there's multiple guides / tutorials on how to use the firewalls in ubuntu

Comment: any chance working solutions, i've tried to edit iptables, but not much changed.

Answer (score 1):

Sendgrid provides rest api and you dont need to open any ports for that. That article refers to setting up your own SMTP server which is not what you want. Have a look at [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html) example which would better explain how you can send mail using sendgrid.